# does GA-A75-UD4H motherboard support booting from SSD?

Tags: ssd, motherboard

I have GA-A75-UD4H motherboard. I want to buy an SSD disk. Will the motherboard be able to boot from the SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the SSD.

[Your motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-A75-UD4H-rev-10#ov) only has SATA ports. As such it can boot from a SATA disk. (Both SSD and rotating rust).

[image]

It has no modern M.2 socket. You can not use a modern SSD, but the legacy SATA based SSDs.